# Reference request for 2-category theory

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, higher-category-theory

In the theory of 2-categories, we have the following theorem.  A pseudofunctor is an equivalence of 2-categories if it is essentially surjective on objects, and the induced functor on Hom categories is an equivalence.  I believe this is a well known result, does anyone know where it is contained that I may reference it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.1877v1. I believe this is Proposition 1.6.